# How to find the n-th multiple of a number using recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion

I need a recursive method in the form of: methodName(int a, int b). The method would return 0 if a is not a multiple of b; or would return the number I need to multiply b with to get a. How can I do that without changing the parameters of the function?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, assume `dividend` and `divisor` are positive.
When using recursion, we need following steps:

1. *Determine Base Case*, which we can easily solve the problem. For example, when `dividend` is less than `divisor`, we know `dividend` will not be a multiple, when `dividend` equals to `divisor`, the multiple will be 1.
2. *Reduce to "easier" problem*. This is the trickiest part. When the problem is more "close" to *Base Case*, it will be "easier". For this question, the problem will be easier when value of `dividend` is smaller, so we try to reduce `dividend` value. One of the possible values to reduce will be `divisor`, as we need to link up the "easier" problem and the "original" problem.
3. *Merge result to "original" problem*. How to merge "easier" problem result to the "original" problem? We need to think about the relation between them.
   `calculateMultiple(dividend, divisor)` = `?` + `calculateMultiple(dividend - divisor, divisor)`
   We see that:
   `?` will be 1 when `dividend` is multiple of `divisor` and
   `?` will be 0 when `dividend` is not multiple of `divisor`

```java
private static int calculateMultiple(int dividend, int divisor) {
    // 1. base case
    if (dividend < divisor) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (dividend == divisor) {
        return 1;
    }
    // 2. reduce to easier problem
    int multiple = calculateMultiple(dividend - divisor, divisor);
    // 3. merge result
    if (multiple == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return multiple + 1;
}
```

Of course, we can modify above method with recursion to support non positive `dividend` and `divisor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what I need. I've spent hours trying to figure out what to do, and came up with nothing. Thanks again, I'll make myself a cup of coffee to read your explanation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this recursively.

```
multiple(int a, int b) {
   return a % b == 0 ? a/b : 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know. But our teacher wants us to create a recursive method for the problem anyways :'(. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: While this answer is helpful and good, maybe OP has a restriction to use recursion for this.

Comment: Both good points!